# Add YYYY-MM column to existing table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Using SQL Server Management Studio - all date columns in date format.

- Table name: dbo.[FP Data]
- Date column (YYYY-MM-DD): order_date
- New date column (YYYY-MM): order-month

I used this query:

```
SELECT
    *,
    FORMAT(order_date,'YYYY-MM') AS order_month
FROM 
    dbo.[FP Data]
```

to create a column in the format `YYYY-MM`. I now want to merge the new column with my table.

(I need in a YYYY-MM format to compare to other data I have in a YYYY-MM format)

Happy to scrap the above if there is a cleverer way to add the YYYY-MM column OR find a way to name the new column as a table and somehow merge the two tables.

Comment: Question:  why are you wanting to store data that can be derived from data that is already in the table?

Comment: I need the date in a yyyy-mm format to compare to another bit of data I also have in a yyyy-mm format

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/specify-computed-columns-in-a-table?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: What about storing the end of month date using `EOMONTH`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a computed column:

```
alter table FPdata add order_month AS FORMAT(order_date,'yyyy-MM')
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ad93628258b6c674d7403239f0744803

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to use the "Alter Table" function to solve your question!

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
ADD column_name data_type column_constraint;
```

Comment: I'm new to SQL would

ALTER TABLE dbo.[FP Data] ADD order_month ('YYYY-MM');

work?

Comment: You would need to use FORMAT(order_date, 'yyyy-MM').
  I'm pretty new myself so we can figure it out together! XD